# reemplazar localhost por mi ip

Tags: php, html, android-studio, base-de-datos

sucede ser que estoy realizando una aplicación Android que se conecta a una BD en php (proyecto escolar), todo esto basándome en un tutorial, en el cual el chico al momento de testear en Android Studio cambia el localhost por su dirección ip, en mi caso realice lo mismo pero no me carga la página.

Estoy usando XAMPP

el link original seria: http://localhost/Salud_TECNM/?pagina=index

pero cuando lo sustituyo por http://192.168.0.4/Salud_TECNM/?pagina=index me aparece:
No se puede acceder a este sitio web192.168.0.4 ha tardado demasiado tiempo en responder.

Prueba a:

Comprobar la conexión
Comprobar el proxy y el cortafuegos
Ejecutar Diagnósticos de red de Windows
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

y esto se tiene que realizar para poder ingresar en el login y nos de al acceso a la información desde la app.

Ya investigue sobre el asunto, pero, no he logrado mucho.

Les agradecería me pudieran ayudar, con una explicación algo sencilla porque todavía no comprendo muchos tecnicismos (sigo trabajando en ello :c)

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega información del servidor, como sistema operativo y software de servidor Web. Probablemente solo necesites abrir un puerto en el firewall.

Comment: Estas utilizando XAMP, WAMP, LAMP USB Webserver? Es necesario que detalles eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es correcto lo que intentas realizar, primero sugiero verificar que la dirección IP de tu equipo es correcta y por recomendación que sea estática (ya que siendo dinámica es muy probable que cambie).

El segundo paso es verificar el puerto que utiliza tu servidor para que de esta manera lo anexes a tu URL, comúnmente los servidores como ApacheTomcat utilizan por defecto el puerto 8080.
Ejemplo:

```
http://192.168.0.4:8080/Salud_TECNM/?pagina=index
```

Asegúrate también de que tu dispositivo con la app pertenece a tu Red local.
En adicional realiza pruebas de comunicación con el comando `ping` en la terminal de windows desde tu servidor a tu dispositivo y biseversa.

Comment: Como añadido, hay que revisar también que el servidor permita conexiones de la red en concreto. Muchos servidores x defecto solo admiten 127.0.0.1 , y hay que configurarles para que admitan 0.0.0.0

Comment: Muchas gracias, en realidad me ayudaron sus comentarios, sin embargo como tengo de proveedor a izzi, no me permite crear el servidor, pero ya lo resolvimos haciendo el servidor en otra computadora.