# Enviar parámetros de conexión desde Android a PHP usando PDO

Tags: php, android, postgresql

Buen día, estoy tratando de enviar parámetros para conectarme a una base de datos `PosgreSQL` desde `Android` a PHP, anteriormente ya habia realizado esta funcionalidad pero usando `MySQL` como base de datos y usando `mysqli` en `PHP` pero ahora es diferente estoy usando `PostgreSQL` como base de datos y `PDO` en `PHP`.

Me explico: Necesito una aplicación la cual al iniciar digite el nombre de la base de datos en un `EditText` para posteriormente conectarse a la base de datos que se ha digitado, la base de datos esta alojada en PostgreSQL y la conexión ya la tengo establecida ahora necesito que la variable `$db_name` por defecto es vacía pero que se le asigne el valor cuando se digite el nombre de la base de datos en el `EditText` desde `Android`.

Mostrare el código que tengo hasta el momento:

En primer lugar tengo mi script `PHP`:

```
<?php 

class Conexion{
    
    function Conectar(){

        $db_name = $_POST['db_name'];
        
        try{
            $conexion = new PDO("pgsql:host=".'MiHost'.";port=5432;db_name=".$db_name,'MiUsuario','MiContraseña');
            return $conexion;
        }catch(Exception $error){
            die("El error de conexion es: ".$error->getMessage());
        }

    }
}

?>
```

-He creado mi clase **conexión** y mi función **conectar** dentro de la función **conectar** he creado un variable sin ningún dato debido a que es el dato que tengo que traer desde `Android`

-Luego tengo los parametros que le estoy pasando: `$conexion = new PDO("pgsql:host=".'MiHost'.";port=5432;dbname=".$db_name,'MiUsuario','MiContraseña');`
Aquí no hay mucho que comentar solo es una simple conexión a `PostgreSQL` sin embargo hay que resaltar que en esta parte: `dbname=".$db_name` le estoy pasando la variable que necesito obtener desde `Android` para que la conexión sea dinámica, hasta este punto supongo que ya se entendió pero es así de simple como asignar el valor del `EditText` de `Android` a la variable de `PHP`.

Hasta aquí todo estaría relativamente bien desde mi punto de vista.

Ahora vamos a **Android Studio**, como explicaba al inicio ya tenia un proceso similar con **MySQL** por lo tanto he utilizado el mismo código el cual es el siguiente:

Empezaría mostrando el `Dialog` donde escribiría el nombre de la base de datos:

```
private void showAlertWithTextInputLayout2(Context context) {
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Dirección IP")
            .setMessage("Por favor, ingrese el nombre de la base de datos\n\nEvite utilizar otro tipo de caracteres y escriba el nombre de la base de datos de forma correcta")
            .setView(editText)
            .setPositiveButton("Realizado", (dialogInterface, i) -> {

                getBaseDeDatos = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                baseDeDatos = getBaseDeDatos;

                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(SplashPrincipal.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(i2);

                }, 5000);

                try {
                    enviarParametro();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            })
            .create();

    dialog.show();
}
```

Abajo del intent tengo un método llamado **enviarParametro()** este es el que nos ayudaría a enviar el parámetro a `PHP`, el cual es así:

```
public void enviarParametro() throws IOException {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    URL url = new URL("http://"+SplashPrincipal.host+":8080/conexiones/conexion.php");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("database", baseDeDatos);
    String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(query);
    System.out.println(query);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    output.close();

    connection.connect();
}
```

Ahora regresando al primer método **enviarParametro()** nos damos cuenta que en la linea `Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("database", baseDeDatos);` le paso dos parámetros el primero es la variable que esta en `PHP` -> `database` y el segundo es la variable que yo escribo en en `EditText` -> `baseDeDatos`

Hasta aquí es donde tengo lo que he realizado, y pues a pesar que he investigado muchísimo y he hecho diferentes pruebas no obtengo el resultado esperado, entonces seguramente hay otra forma para `PDO` o algo estoy haciendo mal o algo tengo que cambiar, sea como sea sinceramente no se que mas podría hacer.

Sin mas espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a solventar el problema de antemano muchas gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema o error? Si dices que ese mismo código funcionaba en otras bases de datos es relativamente fácil hacerlo funcionar con PostgreSQL, solamente tendrías que proporcionar los datos que PostgreSQL exige para la conexión. ¿Tienes algún problema en ese sentido? ¿cuál? ¿Has depurado el código? ¿qué conclusión o mensajes de error sacas de la depuración?

Comment: @A.Cedano simplemente el parámetro no se envía...

Comment: Pues el primer problema que veo es que en tu archivo php la variable `$db_name` recibe solo un `''` por lo que siempre será nada. Deberías hacerlo así: `$db_name = $_POST["db"];` Otro error que noto es tu línea `BasicNameValuePair("dbname", baseDeDatos));` ¿De dónde sacas ese `dbname|?

Comment: ¿Qué parámetro? ¿Desde dónde lo recoges? ¿Qué depuraciones has hecho? ¿Qué resultado arrojan esas depuraciones? ¿Cómo es posible que en un contexto (MySQL) sí se envíen los parámetros y en otro contexto (Postgresql) no? Si se envían en uno no veo motivo por el que en otro no se envíen? En fin, una clave importante siempre es depurar, depurar el código.

Comment: Hola @FranqoBalsamo ya he editado la pregunta gracias por la observación.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano de verdad me gustaría mostrar todo lo que me pides para que sea mas entendible pero lastimosamente no tengo errores de depuración, la pregunta simplemente consiste en mandar una variable de Android a **PHP** para establecer conexión con **PostgreSQL** y a pesar de tener el "código correcto" la variable no se manda y no establezco la conexión.

Comment: Yo no veo exactamente dónde envías la variable, ni hablas de la forma en que has depurado (del lado del servidor) para verificar qué está llegando desde Android (poniendo por ejemplo un `var_dump($_POST);` y revisando en el Logcat lo que imprime). Tampoco dices nada sobre haber verificado que no sea un problema propio de la base de datos (por ejemplo poniendo en el servidor datos directos y verificando si así funciona). No se trata de que relates toooodo lo que has hecho, sino todo lo que has hecho para depurar / resolver este problema. Tampoco es tan complejo como lo imaginas.

Comment: Te consulto, ¿Si usas tu archivo `php` sin las variables, es decir, que escribas la conexión a mano funciona?

Comment: La función `getQuery` parece más pensada para enviar por GET. El encabezado `Content-Type` de `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` haría necesario ese tipo de encoding, pero deberías setearlo con `setRequestProperty`, supongo. `conn.setDoInput(true);` me parece que está de más. En cada caso, imprimí `$_POST['db_name']` para ver si está viendo el valor que le mandás. Intentá enviarlo desde CURL para ver si te llegan los paquetes o es tema de la app de Android. Usá Wireshark o algo parecido para ver lo que estás haciendo con más detalle. Agregá detalle a la publicación. Saludo.

Comment: Hola @FranqoBalsamo si efectivamente funciona de la forma que lo mencionas

Comment: Hola @D4RIO ya he actualizado el código de Android con un método que funciona con POST, gracias por la observación.

Comment: ¿Funciona significa que ya resolviste el problema? En caso contrario, por favor, diagnosticá como te decía arriba. Podés agregar también al diagnóstico la revisión del último log de php. Si no sabés dónde se ubica podés consultar la documentación o buscarlo: `find /var -mtime -2 -a -type f -a -path "*php*.log"` en Linux y unixes, con `-mtime -2` para logs de 2 días o más nuevos. Si lo corrés con `-mmin -5` justo después de probar, deberías ver el archivo que se escribió (5 min a esta parte). Igual imprimir `$_POST['db_name']` deliberadamente es lo que yo haría.

Comment: ¿En el puerto 8080 sirves php? ¿Qué tipo de servidor es?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente no es aconsejable desactivar la política para realizar operaciones en el hilo principal:

```
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

debes usar por ejemplo un AsyncTask,
[¿Cómo usar AsyncTask?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64368/c%C3%B3mo-usar-asynctask)

El problema es que probablemente el valor del host pertenece a una url a la que no puedes realizar la petición

```
   URL url = new URL("http://"+SplashPrincipal.host+":8080/conexiones/conexion.php");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Debes asegurar que esta url este publicada y pueda ser usada por el dispositivo, no uses `localhost`, si es una IP asegura que sea estática.

[Conexión entre Android studio y PostgreSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/484250/conexi%c3%b3n-entre-android-studio-y-postgresql)
[reemplazar localhost por mi ip](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355386/reemplazar-localhost-por-mi-ip)